# Does using methods from one research domain to another research domain counts as scientific contribution?

Tags: publications, research-process, computer-science, research-topic, reproducible-research

If method A was developed and published in XYZ Conference or Journal and then method A was used to address problem B, can it be regarded as a contribution to the research community?

For example, can using ResNet Architecture for industrial computing like nut bolt classification be considered a contribution? (I know is a minor contribution).

Comment: I think this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question. What is the actual underlying problem you are trying to solve? For example, are you trying to obtain a degree where one of the degree requirements is to make a "scientific contribution" and you're wondering if your project will count?

Comment: I suspect the question cannot be answered without seeing the paper in the context of the field. Using methods from one field in a second field is done all the time, so the answer is "yes." But how minor a contribution is too small to count, that's a judgement call.

Comment: @BryanKrause The underlying problem I am trying to solve is the classification task for nut and bolt classification for industrial research. However, method A has been used to classify birds, dogs, or cars. Method A has not been used by anyone else for nut and bolt classification, and I have used it, and the performance is very good. So my question is, is it worth considering as a research contribution? As I have read many research papers which use Method A to solve medical image classification or face classification without changes in Method A itself.

Comment: @techno Sorry, I didn't mean the underlying research problem or whatever, I mean "why does it matter if your work 'counts as a scientific contribution'?" That is, what is the underlying problem you're trying to solve by asking here on Academia.SE whether your work "counts"?

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is "Perhaps, but not necessarily". If a technique from another field gives insight into some class of problems and/or provides insight into important issues, then probably it would be judged a contribution. But it is a judgement call that each researcher would make.

I can envision other situations in which such an application might "work" in the specific context of a paper and, so, imply publish ability, but have no wider significance. Again, a judgement call.

There is no ordained "court" that judges such things.

Hard problems in one field might benefit from what has worked in other fields. Or not.